# Local Changes in exported object not updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I have the following object declaration:

```
var brains = {};
brains.newCode;
brains.threadsBrains = [];
brains.workerActive = [];
brains.arrayBrainsStatus = [];
brains.reset = false;
brains.workers = [];
```

In some part of the same file I have a function which runs after a while:

```
brains.runWorkerBrain = () => {
    brains.arrayBrainsStatus.push({id:robotID,status:"PAUSE",blocking_instruction:false});
};
```

When I import the object in a second file:

```
import brains from '../../../brains/brains-methods.js'
console.log(brains);
```

The result is brains is declared but not updated, in this case arrayBrainStatus.

How can I change the object values and see them into the imported file?

Comment: What do you mean by "run after a while"? If there is a time delay, then `console.log(brains);` runs before `brains.runWorkerBrain` so brain is updated after logging.

Comment: No, I have a HTML button and when I press the button the function is called. So, the `brains` object updates his value.

Comment: Are you logging the value before or after the button is pressed?

Comment: I'm logging the value before the button is pressed. And when I pressed the button no value is not updated.

Comment: How do you know that the value is not updated if you're not logging it after the button is pressed?
Don't you need to log again after the button is pressed to see the updated value?